# Знаки вопроса

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, borland

Здравствуйте! Я скинул программу другу. У меня все нормально, но у друга все Лейблы знаками вопроса - текст в них русский, шрифт стандартный `MS Sans Serif`. Ему скидывал, он устанавливал без изменений, в чем может быть проблема?

У него Windows 7.

Comment: замените их на знаки ответа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Другу нужно в системе поставить "Current language for non-Unicode programs" на русский.

А вам лучше перейти на делфи поновее. C 2009 версии есть поддержка Юникода и таких проблем не возникает.

Если использавание 7 принципально поишите библиотеку "`Tntcomponets`". Там тоже есть поддержка Юникода, но с 2009 года они не развиваются, не знаю есть еще где-то где их можно скачать.

Answer (score 0):

Вась, надо просто в твоем Project`е (допустим, ты назвал программу "Project1" в панели "View Unit" => "Project1") в самом начале дописать вот такую строчку:

```
   SetThreadLocale(1049);
```

Это устанавливает локаль программы еще на этапе её подготовки к запуску. В данном случае устанавливается русская локаль.

---

Такое возникает в неруссифицированых Windows.